# URL rewriting not work in LAMPP server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lampp

I have tried to rewrite this "localhost/myweb/**everything**" into "localhost/myweb/index.php" using this .htacces rules that I put in "/opt/lampp/htdocs/**myweb**" folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

but I found error 500 in my page. In this case Iam using lampp.
I have tried modify httpd.conf with change AllowOveride None to All but still not work.
Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file and read what the issue is. That _always_ has to be the first step you do in cases like that. No sense in guessing what the issue might be if you can read what it actually is.

Comment: In your httpd.conf (vhost or Directory) add : `LogLevel trace6 rewrite:trace6` , this will give you plenty of info about the overall and the rewrite module progress. You should to see what is causing the 500. Dont forget to restart httpd. This should log in the `error.log` if you have made no other mods to logging setup. (apache 2.4)

Comment: @arkascha: Yeaah, Thanks for your Advice. I found " RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters" in error log. and now my "RewriteRule" is working. Thank you so much arkascha.